# How to simplify typesetting of repeated material in math formulae

Tags: math-mode, automation

Is there a way to create something like a reference tag to avoid copy-pasting in math equations.
E.g. if I have something like

```
$ Eq=\prod_{k=1}^{K}(some-very-long-expression)^{z_{k}} $
```

and in the next step I take log of this, I get this

```
$ log(Eq)=\sum_{k=1}^{K}{z_{k}log(some-very-long-expression)} $
```

In that case I would like to create a tag for *some-very-long-expression* part in the first equation and use tag in the second one, so that if there was a mistake in the first line I need to fix it just there.

Comment: I tend to use some “original name” for this, like `\def\**{some-very-long-expression}` (locally defined) and use `\**` in the equation. You can use whatever name you want, but for me that stands out more, or a number like `\0` or `\1`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To be honest it's been some time since I used that, but yes, I used it. Why is it a problem? For me it looks “understandable” `\prod_{k=1}^{K} (\**)^{z_{k}} \qquad \log(Eq) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} z_{k} (\**)`. What is the bravery there? In case `\*` has a definition by default, I did not know that (or not remember that). In any case, as an alternative, one can use `\tmp` or `\0` or `\1` or something like that.

Comment: @Manuel `\*` does have a default definition, and  if you do suggest `\**`   to people you should stress that you are re-defining `\*`  and defining it in a way that produces an error if not followed by `*`, you are not defining a command with name `**` (you probably know that but your comment is there to be read by anyone....) If you use `\newcommand` you would get warned about over-writing a standard latex command and you wouldn't be able to define commands taking null delimited arguments delimited by `*`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've seen it does have a definition, but I can't understand what it does! (The `\discretionary` outputs a `\times` symbol?). In any case, yes, I wasn't talking about defining in general but about defining locally, e.g., `$ \def\** .. $`, `\[ \def\** .. \]`. But in case it might create great confusion I can remove the comment.

Comment: @Manuel a local definition would not serve the requested use case of using the same term in two equations (discretionary times is so you can use conjunction for implied multiplication `abc` but add explicit operator at line breaks (it comes from plain tex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LaTeX, one may use `\newcommand` to define a new command or, to use the jargon term, macro. Here's a compilable example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mymacro{\mbox{(some-very-long-expression)}} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Eq = \prod_{k=1}^{K} \mymacro^{z_{k}}
\end{equation}
followed by
\begin{equation}
\log(Eq) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} z_{k} \log \mymacro
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```